# Unable to build .sty files with MikTeX

Tags: packages, installing, build-system

I need to build the .sty of different packages to be loaded in my input file (I have to do things manually). I am working on Windows and get a very strange behaviour: `latex.exe` seems to be missing the file I want to build even if I run `latex.exe` in the directory containing the `.ins` file. What's going on?

EDIT: I am using Miktex

```
C:\Travail\Tools\localtexmf\tex\latex\tocloft>ls
README  texput.log  tocloft.dtx  tocloft.ins  tocloft.pdf  tocloft.sty

C:\Travail\Tools\localtexmf\tex\latex\tocloft>latex.exe tocloft.ins
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `tocloft.ins'.
<*> tocloft.ins
```

It looks like it is more or less randomely working, sometimes I can build, sometimes not...

Comment: NICE I get it now ! It is a valid answer I think... feel free to write it as such

Comment: Glad my comment was on target! I've written it up as a full answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of MikTeX's (more or less well known) "features" is that it doesn't automatically find newly installed files -- in your case, `tocloft.dtx` and `tocloft.ins` -- in the current working directory *if* that directory happens to be in the search path of the TeX distribution, whether in the main directory tree or in the "localtexmf" directory tree.

One must update the filename database to get MikTeX to "find" such files. Clicking on the "Update FNDB" button in the MikTeX Settings utility will fix the problem.