# Reledmac & indextools : Indexing a word inside a critical note problem

Tags: indexing, french, reledmac

I'm really sorry to bother you, but I have a small problem with `reledmac` and `indextools`.

I'm doing a thesis editing an old French manuscript. I am using several layers of critical notes and doing two indexes. 
I have tried to follow the handbook for the `reledmac` to solve the issue but I must be missing something out.

When I want to index a word that is inside a critical note, most of the time the index definition ends up in the critical note, on top of being in the index, which I don't want. When I try fixing it, it messes the text (missplacing the punctuation or forgetting the `&`) or issues an error warning.

Here is a part of my thesis, the problem coming from the line:
   `Et \edtext{ainsy au definement.\edindex[glo]{definement@\textsc{Definement}, subst. m. <<~fin~>>}}{\Bfootnote{MN e. me doint bon avancement. A e. nous doint bon amendement. H e. me doint bon commancement.}}&`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{indextools}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\makeindex[name = glo, title = Glossaire, columns = 2, columnseprule]
\makeindex[name = npr, title = Index des noms propres, columns = 2, columnseprule]

\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xlemmaseparator{~:}
\numberpstarttrue

\mainmatter

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\linenumincrement{4}
\firstlinenum{0}
\setstanzaindents{2,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\let\endstanzaextra\bigbreak
\stanza
\hspace{0.5cm} \textit{Tristis est anima mea}.&
Jhesu Crist\edindex[npr]{Jhesu Crist@\textsc{Jhesu Crist}, <<~fils de Dieu~>>}, qui tant aimé a&
Les siens que d’enfer les getta\edindex[glo]{getta@\textsc{Getter*}, vb. tr. <<~libérer~>>},&
Et de son sang les racheta,&
Soit a ce mon conmencement&
Et \edtext{ainsy au definement.\edindex[glo]{definement@\textsc{Definement}, subst. m. <<~fin~>>}}{\Bfootnote{MN e. me doint bon avancement. A e. nous doint bon amendement. H e. me doint bon commancement.}}&
J’ay bien cause d’espandre lermes~!&
\endnumbering
\newpage
\printindex[glo]
\printindex[npr]
\end{document}
```

I know I'm using `indextools` as a glossary and that I should probably use the package `glossaries`, but I really don't understand this package and I am bit more familiar with `indextools` (even though I'm still trying to find a way to change the style =) )

PS: I should warn anyone who tries to help me, I'm a bit of a newbie, sorry if I don't understand quickly.

Comment: I will look on it,  but just a point: why are you using `\hspace{0.5cm}` ? I think "Tristis est anima mea" is not a line of verse, but a title, so that should be in optional argument of \stanza.

Comment: It is a bug of edindex when using command insided \edindex argument and using \edindex inside \edtext.

Comment: Please open a github issue. I think that could be solved quickly.

Comment: I have opened the issue https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preliminaries remarks

You should have written `J’ay bien cause d’espandre lermes~!\&` instead of `J’ay bien cause d’espandre lermes~!&`.

## Your problem

1. As you call your `\edindex` inside `\edtext`, that means you want having index twice:

   1. One for main text.
   2. One for critical footnotes, whereas the `\edindex` is also called, as all the content of `\edtext`.

That was a bug of reledmac, which was in contradiction with the handbook.

2. There were also a second bug, when using formatting command inside  `\edindex` inside  `\edtext`.

<s>3. These two bugs are normally solved on github branch issue650.
 1. Download https://codeload.github.com/maieul/ledmac/zip/issue650
 2. Unzip it.
 3. Run reledmac.ins file to get reledmac.sty file
 4. Push reledmac.sty file along your .tex file
 5. In case of problem, make remarks on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/650
 6. I will publish it on CTAN this week.</s>

3. These two bugs are solve on v 2.21.0 of reledmac, now on CTAN.

### Other problems

1. Don't use anymore `\let\endstanzaextra\bigbreak`  but use `\AtEveryStopStanza{\bigbreak}`.
2. Use optional argument of `\stanza` to add your title without including it in line counter.
3. Define a command for your title, instead of doing `\hspace{0.5cm} \textit{Tristis est anima mea}.`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to install this version of reledmac even though I have been trying to get the reledmac.sty since yesterday and keep failing [newbie].

Comment: For the \hspace{0.5cm}, it is just to get a small space at the beginning of the stanza. Tristis est anima mea being the first verse and not the title of my text. And for your preliminary remark, it is just because I only gave a small portion of my work, I know I have to finish a stanza by \&. Thanks again (and sorry to post multiple commentaries, I failed ^^)

Comment: I think your are on MikTeX, and there is some problem for compiling .ins file with MikTeX, if I remember well. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126012/7712).

Comment: I have posted a version of the .sty file on https://framadrop.org/r/IkeZ7nBimL#Zkr900WO5CG4WcBUjb/lso0wiJEWs3gkfOaVWaVFeDY=

Comment: For your `\hspace`, ok, my bad, but I think you shoul define your `\mytitlecommand`: `\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\hspace{0.5cm}\emph{#1}`. If you will need to change the setup, you will have only one line to modify.

Comment: For your `\&` the problem is that, on StackExchange, you need to put a MWE which is runnable without interruption, except if you want to show a specific interruptions. Here, the final `&` create a not problem-related interruption.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry fort the \&, I should have realised it would have prevented the compilation. I'll keep in mind what you said about the \hspace. Thanks a lot for the .sty file. I finally succeeded in getting it after an hour of internet research. I am indeed using the MikTeX.

Comment: The final problem is that I don't really understand where to put the .sty files and how to make sure it works. I have tried to put it directly in C:>Program Files (x86) > MiKTeX 2.9 > tex > latex and creating a file named reledmac. But it didn't seem to do anything. So I tried to relocate it creating a Local Tex Files in C and indicating MikTeX to search for it there, but when I run my document it still has the same issue.

Comment: normally, you just put your file in the samefolder than you .tex file. It is just for test. When I will have pushed new version on CTAN, you will use the MikTeX upgrade mechanism.

Comment: On your .log file, it is told which files are used.

Comment: It works !!! I forgot to uninstall the previous version of reledmac on the MikTeX Package Manager, so it wasn't searching for the new .sty file. Thanks a lot ! The problem is fixed =)

Comment: Happy to see it's work. But don't forget: it is better to use MikTeX manager install of installing your .sty file manually. Here, you did it only for tests. You should subscribe to reledmac users list http://geekographie.maieul.net/146 to get new about public release. I will release it this week, next week end at least. In this case, you should uninstall your manually installation and use miktex manager.

Comment: Ok, I suscribed. Thanks again ! Now that I know how to install / uninstall, that will be easy